# How to work for camera App in API 19 since android.hardware.Camera was deprecated in API level 21 and SDK updated to level 23 of android studio?

Tags: android

How to work for camera App in API 19 since android.hardware.Camera was deprecated in API level 21 and the SDK was updated to level 23 of my android studio?

Answer (score 2):

"Deprecated" in the Android SDK means "we have something else that is a long-term replacement for this". In some cases, you can use the alternative immediately, such as when the alternative comes from a support library. In other cases, you can only use the replacement on newer devices.

`android.hardware.Camera` still works on all API levels. So, your choices are:

1. Use `android.hardware.Camera` for all devices, or
2. Use `android.hardware.Camera` for older devices and `android.hardware.camera2.*` on API Level 21+ devices, or
3. Set your `minSdkVersion` to 21 and only use `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes